# Most efficient way in Laravel to query across two connections

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two connections, 'mysql' and 'mysql2' hosted on two different boxes.

On 'mysql' there is a table called 'account', on 'mysql2' there is a table called 'payments' which uses PayPal IPN to accept payments.

I'm pulling out data from 'mysql2' using a model called 'Payment' and there's a field on 'payments' called 'custom' which contains the User ID from who made a PayPal payment. I would like to 'link' these two up somehow so I can pull the username of the payer.

I believe leftJoin won't work in this situation as it's across two connections, would Eloquent's relationships methods work? I have tried using them to no avail.

My query is like so:

```
$top_donators = Payment::selectRaw('month(created_at) as month, year(created_at) as year, sum(mc_gross) as amount, custom')
                                ->groupBy('year', 'month', 'custom')
                                ->orderBy('amount','desc')
                                ->get();
```

User Model Relationship

```
public function payment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Payment', 'custom', 'id');
    }
```

Payment Model Relationship

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Is it not more feasible to use the same database for both tables?

Comment: It probably would be yes; but unfortunately not possible. User database is accounts for a game which is hosted on a powerful machine, and website hosted externally which is where the payments take place. Last time we tried hosting our website externally and not localhost, it was going at snail speed :x

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try adding 
`protected $connection = 'mysql';` to your `Accounts` model and `protected $connection = 'mysql2';` to your `Payments` model.</strike>

In your relationship, try specifying `[database].[tablename].[columnname]` as an argument.

e.g. `return $this->belongsTo('User','mysql2.users.id');`

Source: http://laravel.io/forum/02-12-2014-many-to-many-relationship-not-working-across-databases

Comment: Thanks, correct connections were already set up. Sorry wasn't in my original post.

Comment: No luck :( I decided to save the username and other data on the website host box once someone logs into the game in the background. Not really the workaround I wanted..but it works for now